# ListContourPlot is blank

Tags: graphics, plotting

This is probably very simple.  I want to do a simple `ListContourPlot`.

```
contourData = Table[ myFunc[x,y], {x,0.1, 2.9}, {y,0.1, 2.9}];
ListContourPlot[contourData]
```

This works without a problem.

Now, I want to include x and y values so that I can show the values corresponding to specific values of x and y. I modify the Table statement to include x and y values.

```
contourData = Table[ {x,y, myFunc[x,y]}, {x,0.1, 2.9}, {y,0.1, 2.9}];
ListContourPlot[contourData]
```

My contour plot is now blank. I'm guessing it is a problem with the Table statement.  The maximum minus minimum over this range is about 220.  As this is a function of Pythagorean distance, the values vary (so I don't think it is a case of essentially equal values over the ranges of x and y.

What is the correct way to generate data for a ListContourPlot?

Comment: Try `ListContourPlot[Flatten[contourData, 1]]`.

Comment: That was it exactly!  Thank you most kindly!

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to @ b.gatessucks excellent comment you might consider `DataRange`:

```
ListContourPlot[Table[Sin[x + y], {x, 0, 3, 0.1}, {y, 0, 3, 0.1}], 
   DataRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}}]
```

[image]